# How to apply K-means cluster for villagewise in single dataframe, how to automatically determine the number of Clusters villagewise

Tags: python, pandas, cluster-analysis, k-means

I want to determine number of clusters based on village wise, i.e Village1 data separately, village2 data separately ...village n data separately...

I know how to determine number of clusters using k-means for single village(Single data).
But now I have 500 Villages, and each villages there are total 50,000 rows.

so I want to apply data set as a single village--single dataframe...and apply k-means cluster identify number of cluster required for each villages separately

Is there any dynamic way for do this using function or so on..?

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> clustNos = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
>>> Inertia = []
>>> from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
>>> for i in clustNos :
    model = KMeans(n_clusters=i)
    model.fit(df)
    Inertia.append(model.inertia_)



>>> plt.plot(clustNos, Inertia, '-o')
>>> plt.title("Scree Plot")
>>> plt.xlabel('Number of clusters, k')
>>> plt.ylabel('Inertia')
>>> plt.xticks(clustNos)
>>> plt.show()
>>> model = KMeans(n_clusters=4)
>>> model.fit(df)
KMeans(algorithm='auto', copy_x=True, init='k-means++', max_iter=300,
       n_clusters=4, n_init=10, n_jobs=None, precompute_distances='auto',
       random_state=None, tol=0.0001, verbose=0)
>>> labels = model.predict(df)
>>> clusterID = pd.DataFrame(labels)
>>> clusteredData = pd.concat([df,clusterID],axis=1)
>>> clusteredData.rename(columns={0:'Group'})
```

[image]